# jQuery Touch Events binds itself on everything

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, scroll, touch

I'm working with a plugin that needs to prevent scrolling.

On desktop it's pretty easy:

```
$( document ).css({
    overflow: 'hidden'
});
```

but on mobile it won't work because it will only hide the scrollbar and it won't prevent from scrolling, so it's pretty hard!!!

I need the document not to scroll (even on mobile), BUT I need that things in a DIV will scroll.

DEMO: http://dcdev.altervista.org/test/test.html

On desktop it works fine, but on mobile it will prevent from scrolling everywhere in the document!

I tried this way:

```
<style>
.box {
    position: fixed;
    top: 3em;
    right: 3em;
    left: 3em;
    bottom: 3em;
    border: 3px solid green;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left; 0;
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
</style>


<body>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="text">A VERY LONG TEXT</div>
    </div>

<script>
    var touch = function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    },
        $this = $( '.box' ),
        textBox = $this.children( ':first-child' );

    $( document ).not( textBox ).bind( 'touchmove', touch )

    $( 'body' ).css( 'overflow', 'hidden' );
</script>
</body>
```

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

You could lock it in place by setting `position : fixed` and set the `top` via JS by calculating how far it has scrolled. That way, it doesn't move. Make sure `.box` has `position:relative` so `.text`'s position is relative to `.box`.

Comment: var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();

$( 'html' ).css({ position: 'fixed', top: scrollTop, left: 0, right: 0, 'overflow-y' : 'hidden' });

this works on desktop but not on mobile!